# facebook like button does not show up

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

Im trying to implement facebook like button on my site. But the problem is , that the button just doesnt show up. I am opening it on localhost.
I used the code from developers.facebook
here it is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sk_SK/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: _“I am opening it on localhost”_ –does this mean your are calling your pages via HTTP in the browser, using an actual local webserver? If not, and you are just viewing the page over the file system, then the protocol-relative URL for the SDK, `//connect.facebook.net/…`, can not work. In that case, you can put `http:` before it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried fill the 'width' form on the facebook site? The button will not show up if you didn't determent the width of the button. I've help you. Here's the code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="50" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: Yes i tried fill "width" form . But still the button does not show up.

Comment: I've checked the code on my localhost too, and it's working. maybe there's a problem behind the scene. try inspect element and see the problem. also, try it on a new fresh index file.

Comment: i have tried it on new fresh page. Still didnt work. When i inspect elements the fb element are displayed with "low opacity" in firebug , like they was avaible.

Comment: upload it to a server. I recommend hostinger. I think the error is on your xampp or your client(you). also, try to turn on the openssl on php.ini. search for google if you don't know.